# java How To override the hashcode() and equals() of a specific arrayList item

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashset, hashcode

ok so my question is fairly simple. I have searched StackOverFlow, google, and the JavaDocs high and low, but can't seem to find an answer to my specific question.

As I understand it (boiling it down to the basics here), every object gets a `hashCode()` as a unique identifier. We'll use this as an example...

```
class Team {
        public Team(String teamName){teamName.this = teamName;}
        String teamName;
    }

    class NBALeague {
        ArrayList<Team> teamsInALeague = new ArrayList<>();
        teamsInALeague.add(new Team("Rockets"));
        teamsInALeague.add(new Team("Warriors"));
        teamsInALeague.add(new Team("Cavaliers"));
        teamsInALeague.add(new Team("76ers"));
    //each unique team when instantiated is assigned a hashCode!

        //now when I change the objects (or add to them rather) they are then 
        //each given a new hashCode()

          public void buildASchedule(){
             Team rockets = teamsInALeague.get(0);
             Team warriors= teamsInALeague.get(1);
             Team cavaliers= teamsInALeague.get(2);
             Team philly= teamsInALeague.get(3);

             String definingString = "This Team is Called: ";

             ArrayList anotherArrayList = new ArrayList();

             anotherArrayList.add(definingString + rockets.teamName);
             //Moving an object from one array list to another doesnt affect
             //its hashcode(), but adding a string to the object does
```

Now that `anotherArrayList.get(0)` has a brand new hashcode, how would I override it?

I know i have to override the `hashcode()` and `equals()` method in order to ensure that, when placing into a HashSet, the set can identify duplicates, but because these new hashcodes are made when adding a string to the object i don't know how to override hashcode. Normally I would override both methods through the Team class, but again that wont work seeing as changing an object creates a new hashcode. somebody help please!!!

Comment: You override the methods by extending the class

Comment: well, even if i extended the class i wouldnt be able to target the specific concatenated item using the override method.... if you could show me an example that would be great! and much appreciated!

Comment: The default implementation of hashcode will return the same hash for the same object. If the ojbect has a String field and you populate the field, the hash will still be the same. If you see it changes it is because it is a different object being created.

Comment: "every object gets a hashCode() as a unique identifier" Nope. It's not a unique ID. It's an integer, so there's around 5 billion possibilities but [you don't actually need very many objects to be fairly certain of a collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: hmm...great explanation...ok maybe my example was too simplified for my actual problem. 
Lets pretend that the "teamName" field didnt exist. In the event that a object is concatenated to a another object to form an arrayList item to (for  instance if I took : anotherArrayList.add(rockets + warriors);
and that creates a new  hashcode(), how would i override that new new specific hashcode?

Comment: You are missing the point completely. Overriding these methods is pointless unless every instance of the class does it the same way. That's why it is designed as an OO feature. And you can't add objects together as shown in your comment unless at least one of them is a String, and the result of that is another String, which can't be added to the ArrayList you showed in your code.

Comment: oh wow...so basically what I am trying to do isnt possible. Ok thanks for your time. if you know of any work-arounds- please post as answer

Comment: one last thing. you said that if i add an object to a string and that becomes  anew string, that new string is given a new hashcode. how would I override THAT hashcode? because it started off as an object + a string to create a new string? which class hashcode()/equals() would i have to override and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two misconceptions: what `hashCode` actually is, and how the `+` operator works.

I'll address the latter first. Apart from assignment (`=`), when you apply an operator on an object, it does not change the object in any way. The statment

```
anotherArrayList.add(definingString + rockets.teamName);
```

does not change or affect the `rockets` variable in any way. It does not "change the hashCode" or any other thing about it, it simply copies the value of `rockets.teamName`, joins it with something else, and creates a brand new object. And that brand new object will be a String, so you cannot add it to the list anyway.

Now, about hashCode. Objects are not "assigned a hashCode" or anything like that. There's nothing special or magical or automatic about hashCode(), it is just a method that returns an integer. It returns what you tell it to return, and, if you do not override it, the default implementation returns a number that **never** changes for a given object.

If you *replace* the object with another one, for example by putting another `Team` in that position in the list, then that object will have its own hashCode that may differ from the first. But simply using the object or one of its fields
does not affect it in any way.

Comment: NEW EDIT:

ArrayList<String> anotherArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
anotherArrayList.add(definingString + rockets.teamName);

as stated this doesnt change the original values.
but it does create a new object that is a combined string
Now lets say I want to put this new string into a hashset and I want to make sure that no 2 strings show up twice
I realize that I must override the hashcode() and equals() method, but since these are new strings that are not Team objects would i override these methods in the NBA Leagues class? if so can someone show an example please